# Trying to run a simple angular app, but angular not loading

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run this angular app locally: https://jsfiddle.net/alexsuch/6aG4x/

I created an index.html, and an app.js and copied the respective code to each file. In the html file I added...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src= "app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am running http-server from the console to load the app. When I visit localhost:8080 I see the {{ content }} so I know angular is not loading.

Here are my files...

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='store'>
<body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container">
  <h1>Select text file</h1>
    <input type="file" on-read-file="showContent($fileContent)" />
    <div ng-if="content">
        <h2>File content is:</h2>
        <pre>{{ content }}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src= "app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
</body>
```

## app.js

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showContent = function($fileContent){
        $scope.content = $fileContent;
    };
  });

myapp.directive('onReadFile', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);

            element.on('change', function(onChangeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        fn(scope, {$fileContent:onLoadEvent.target.result});
                    });
                };

                reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you do basic debugging? Open console and it will tell you *why*.

Comment: could you put your files please?

Comment: @dfsp yes, opened the chrome inspector and no errors are being thrown

Comment: change `ng-app='store'` to `ng-app="myapp"`

Comment: Seriously! No error?! Are you sure? Because I can clearly see the error. There is not module myapp.

Comment: Your app in your html doc is listed as "store" but in your JS file it's "myapp".  Those need to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are bootstrap a module named :'store' with this `<html ng-app='store'>`

rename `myapp` to `store` is this line `angular.module('myapp', []);`

Comment: Boom! You nailed it dude! Works like charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The name of your angular app is incorrect and is different in HTML and JavaScript. It should be consistent between the `ng-app` directive and the `angular.module('', [])` declaration. Change it as below to make the app work:

**Change in JavaScript**

```
var myapp = angular.module('store', []);
```

**Change in HTML**

```
<html ng-app='myapp'>
```

See a working demo of the same here: https://jsbin.com/geyidot/1/edit?html,js,console,output